# Trying to remove old version and install new

Tags: installation

CiviCRM was causing an error 500 on the site.  I renamed the com_civicrm directory in root joomla and in administrator folders I now get Warning: `require_once(/hsphere/local/home/kencostore/yesmilwaukee.org/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /hsphere/local/home/kencostore/yesmilwaukee.org/plugins/user/civicrm/civicrm.php on line 103 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/hsphere/local/home/kencostore/yesmilwaukee.org/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php' (include_path='.:/hsphere/shared/php55/include/php/PEAR') in /hsphere/local/home/kencostore/yesmilwaukee.org/plugins/user/civicrm/civicrm.php on line 103`

Can someone please let me know where else there's a reference to civicrm that needs to be removed.  I plan on reinstalling and I have backed up the site's database

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `civicrm.settings.php` file may still be looking in the `com_civicrm` directory for your Civi files.  You will also need to make sure that your "CiviCRM Resource URL" directory on the Settings-Resources URL screen has been updated (Top black menu > Administer > System settings > Resource URLs).